# nth-child and if else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, css-selectors

Is it possible to achieve the following using nth-child and an if else statement?

Say there are 9 divs and each one has a link inside that when clicked performs a function. Could I somehow have the the link figure out what nth-child div (from the body tag) it is inside and perform the function only if it's inside the 3rd, 6th or 9th div? I really have no idea where to begin but it seems possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**nth-clild**](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/),

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Fwqxv/)**

```
$('.divclass :nth-child(3n)')
```

For binding event, you can use [click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Fwqxv/4/)**

```
$('#divId div:nth-child(3n) a').click(function(){
  alert($(this).text());    
});​
```

Answer (score 2):

[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/udinaj/2/edit)

```
$('div:nth-child(3n)').find('a').click(function( e ){

  e.preventDefault();

  alert( $(this).text() );

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('divclass:nth-child(3n)').find('a').on('click',function(){
    alert( $(this).text() );
});
```

Hope this works :) cheers

Comment: The `live` method is deprecated, so I don't think is a good way to suggest answers

Comment: yes @roXon , Live is deprecated now .However we can use .on()

Comment: like this 

$('divclass:nth-child(3n)').find('a').on('click',function(){
alert( $(this).text() );
});

Comment: Edited your answer although I really don't know where's the specifically mentioned need for the use of `.on()` ...